# Chromadepth and distance?

Tags: color, 3d

I am making some 3D graphics meant to be viewed using Chromadepth 3D glasses.

http://chromatek.com/

My question is, is the 3D effect linear over virtual distance, or is the change in effect nonlinear and stronger at short distances than long distances? E.g.

`color = arctan(distance from camera)`

Thanks.

[edit]

I can ask on the physics forum instead.

Comment: So, 3D graphic design is off-topic on this site?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but its too long, so I take a risk to collect a bunch of downvotes because the subject is interesting.

Math theory behind Chromadepth  glasses belongs to physics - not claiming that nobody  here cannot understand that math, but I believe we draw more and  calculate less.

The glasses have complex multilayer prisms or ultrafine diffraction grids which cause controlled chromatic aberration. The prisms or grids are designed to cause  pre-determined wavelength dependent direction changes to the lightrays.

The glasses move the apparent XY-position of a colored dot towards the watchers nose. The effect is proportional (linearly or not, unknown for me) to the frequency of the lightwaves. Thus blue seems to be closer than red. The effect obviously is added somehow to the actual watching distance.

How does it work with RGB or CMYK colors which definitely are not "one wavelength per one color hue"? Obviously it works - thanks for the supercomputer behind the eyes. Otherwise it would be quite useless (=buy the glasses and draw only with their monochromatic special crayons, carefully avoiding any color mixing)

Without having a pair of those glasses I cannot decide are they any good and does my head notice any linearity between hue differences and apparent distance differences. Do I get headache because there's also the physical watching distance making an angle between the rays?

I would take an image of a ruler with centimeter scale and color it with a gradient to see myself. A colored perspective grid would be the next.

Get a pair and try. The manufacturer can also give some technical details to the buyers. Ask for them. Then answer to your question yourself. There's one percent possiblity that it stays open. But you can edit my answer.

BTW. Read also the patent. http://www.google.com/patents/US5002364?hl=en

Comment: Physics SE says it's not a topic for their forum either. Also, I don't trust my eyes enough to use a ruler.